# Next.js component is creating multiple Lightweight Charts

Tags: next.js, lightweight-charts

I was trying to create Lightweight Charts in Next.js. Firstly, I created chart component which accepts chart data as props.

```
import { createChart, CrosshairMode } from 'lightweight-charts';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const CandleStickChart = ({ OHLC_Data }) => {
    const chartContainerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const chart = createChart(chartContainerRef.current, {
            width: 700,
            height: 400,
            timeScale: {
                timeVisible: true,
                secondsVisible: false,
                fixLeftEdge: true,
                fixRightEdge: true,
            },
            crosshair: {
                mode: CrosshairMode.Normal,
            },
        });
        const candleSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries({
            priceFormat: {
                type: 'price',
                minMove: 0.00001,
                precision: 5,
            },
        });

        candleSeries.setData(OHLC_Data);
    }, [OHLC_Data]);


    return <div ref={chartContainerRef} />;
};

export default CandleStickChart;
```

In page component, I used getServerSideProps to fetch the data required for chart.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import Image from 'next/image';

const CandleStickChart = dynamic(
    () => import('../../components/CandleStickChart'),
    { ssr: false }
);

import { fetchTimeSeries } from '../../utils/fetchData';

const ForexPair = ({ meta, hour, day, week }) => {
    const { currency_base, currency_quote, symbol, type } = meta;
    const [logos, setLogos] = useState(null);

    return (
        <>
            <CandleStickChart OHLC_Data={hour.values} />
            <CandleStickChart OHLC_Data={day.values} />
            <CandleStickChart OHLC_Data={week.values} />                
        </>
    );
};

export default ForexPair;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { params, res } = context;
    const { pairSymbol } = params;

    res.setHeader(
        'Cache-Control',
        'public, s-maxage=300, stale-while-revalidate=3600'
    );

    const { meta, hour, day, week } = await fetchTimeSeries(
        pairSymbol.replace('-', '/')
    );

    return {
        props: {
            meta,
            hour,
            day,
            week,
        },
    };
}
```

I excluded some unnecessary codes. `fetchTimeSeries` function is just asynchronous function to fetch data for third party api. `getServerSideProps` is returning data format required in `<CandleStickChart />` component.

What I expect to see is total 3 charts since I only included 3  components. but I am seeing two of each charts, total of 6 charts.

Please dont yell at me if my code looks terrible, I am new to Next.js :D. I really have no idea what is happening in my app.
p.s Charts are displaying correctly, just seeing duplicate charts for each. Thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the way React & `useEffect` works under the hood.

Just add

```
return () => {
    chart.remove();
};
```

after `candleSeries.setData(OHLC_Data);` and you won't see duplications :)